# Find whether two columns match based on existence of words in the same row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two columns of interest. I want to try to compare the two columns word-wise and find out whether any words overlap. If so, I want to append a column that indicates that matching words were found within the row.

Here's an example of my dataframe:

```
df
    name1      name2
0   cat nip    giant cat
1   bad dog    blue sky
2   slow snail slimy snail
3   tall tree  big boy
```

Here's what I want:

```
df
    name1      name2       found
0   cat nip    giant cat   True
1   bad dog    blue sky    False
2   slow snail slimy snail True
3   tall tree  big boy     False
```

I've tried many methods. One method was using this code:

```
df['found'] = df['name1'].apply(lambda x: any(i in df['name2'] for i in x))
```

Which didn't work. Second method was using this code:

```
glossary = list(set(df['name1']))
pattern = '|'.join(glossary)
check = df[(df.name1.str.contains(pattern))& 
        (df.name2.str.contains(pattern))]
```

This code didn't work either, and it was creating a new dataframe (which I don't want). Plus both methods were really slow. Any ideas how to do it correctly?

Also, I've already tried the `isin` method:

```
df['found'] = df['name1'].isin(df['name2'])
```

which doesn't work either. It gives me many false `True` labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple solution using `&` between series.

First [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.transform.html) your lists to `set`

```
transf_1 = df.name1.str.split(" ").transform(set)
transf_2 = df.name2.str.split(" ").transform(set)
```

Then just

```
>>> transf_1 & transf_2.values

0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
```

Comment: This did it. And it's very fast. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Or try this:

```
df['found'] = [True if set(i['name1'].split()).intersection(i['name2'].split()) else False for idx,i in df.iterrows()]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    name1      name2       found
0   cat nip    giant cat   True
1   bad dog    blue sky    False
2   slow snail slimy snail True
3   tall tree  big boy     False
```